# How Can I Pass Function Through A Toggle Swiftui

Tags: function, swiftui, notifications, switch-statement, toggle

### State var:

`@State var toggleIsOn = false`

### Toggle:

```
Toggle(isOn: $toggleIsOn, label: {Text("Notifications")})
```

I want the following buttons, to represent each state of the toggle, on and off:

```
                // Will request to send notifications, if success; will schedule them.
                Button("request") {
                    NotificationManager.instance.requestAuthorization()
                }
                // Will clear the queue of notifications, and delete any delivered.
                Button("cancel") {
                    NotificationManager.instance.cancelNotifications()
                }
```

I found the functions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mG9BVAs8AIo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### use

> onChange(of:)

### for example:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggleIsOn: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $toggleIsOn, label: {Text("Notifications")})
        .onChange(of: toggleIsOn) { isOn in
             if isOn {
                  NotificationManager.instance.requestAuthorization()
             } else {
                  NotificationManager.instance.cancelNotifications()
             }
        }
    }
}
```